# Writing a multi-index dataframe to Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The DataFrame MultiIndex is kicking my butt. After struggling for quite a while, I was able to create a MutliIndex DataFrame with this code

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Zip', ''),
('All Properties', 'Avg List Price'),('All Properties', 'Median List Price'),
('3 Bedroom', 'Avg List Price'),('3 Bedroom', 'Median List Price'),
('2 Bedroom', 'Avg List Price'),('2 Bedroom', 'Median List Price'),
('1 Bedroom', 'Avg List Price'),('1 Bedroom', 'Median List Price')])
data[0] = ['11111', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4', 'Val5', 'Val6', 'Val7', 'Val8']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Everything looks fine until I try to write it to an excel file

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testData.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

When I open the excel file this is what I get.
[image]

If I unmerge the columns in Excel all the data is there.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to create
[image]

I'm guessing that the problem has something to do with the way I'm creating the multi index columns, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

I'm running python 2.7 on a Mac.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that will be fixed in version 0.17.1, or you can use `engine='xlsxwriter'`

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11328

Comment: upgrading to the development build fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use for `itertools.product`. Try this instead in your multiindex creation:

```
from itertools import product
cols = product(
    ['All Properties', '3 Bedroom', '2 Bedroom', '1 Bedroom'],
    ['Avg List Price', 'Median List Price']
)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(cols))
ind = pd.Index(['11111'], name='zip')
vals = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4', 'Val5', 'Val6', 'Val7', 'Val8']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    vals, index=ind, columns=columns
)
```

The issue is: you included zip (which names your *index*) in the construction of your MultiIndex for your *columns* (tragically, nothing called `MultiColumns` exists to clear up that confusion). You need to create your Index (which is a single-level normal `pandas.Index`) and your columns (which are a two-level `pandas.MultiIndex`) separately, as above, and you should get expected behavior when you write to excel.

Comment: This does appear to be a more 'correct' way to implement the code, however it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Adrian Ah, I read the OP's MultiIndex construction incorrectly/believe it was creating extra values based on my misreading. Woops.