# Text Merging for column header in Python for csv

Tags: python, csv, xlsxwriter

I want to create a csv file in which there are First 2 rows dedicated for heading and rest are columns for each second row header, is it programatically possible in Python ?

I tried searching for keyword like `text merging` and `column header concatenation` in [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) official docs but nothing good came out. Had it been single header and single column thing I have already done it using python [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Ex.

```
_________________________________________________________
|____Big_Heading_1______|_____Big_Heading_2_______|_____|    
|SH_1_|__SH_2_|__SH_3___|_SH_1_|__SH_2_|__SH_3____|_SH1_|
|D1   |  D2   |  D4     | D5   |  D6   |   D7     | D8  |
|D9   |  D10  |  D11    | D12  |  D13  |   D14    | D15 |
```

Notations : `SH = Small Heading, D  = Data`

Note: In place of third `Big Heading` there is nothing which for that particular there is no `Big Heading` ie. `Big Heading` equals to `Small Heading`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with [merged cells](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html) in xlsxwriter.

A slightly better way is using pandas [MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710771/writing-a-multi-index-dataframe-to-excel-file). This way you create a dataframe and let `to_excel()` method handle the export.

Comment: The docs follow Excel terminology for doing things, that was the trick. )