# Add new header to existing columns in excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below mentioned . I want to add new header in existing dataframe as expected result . Can anyone please help me to do this.

**One:**

```
   Name    Std   Tamil  Maths   Score  Result     Status
  Shankar   10    90     100     190     Pass      Good
  Shankar   10    50      20      70     Fail      Bad
```

I want to add **Subjects and Grade** as a header in existing frame

**Expected Result:**

```
                 Subjects         Grade
  Name    std   Tamil  Maths    Score  Result       Status
 Shankar   10    90     100      190     Pass        Good
 Shankar    10    50      20       70     Fail        Bad
```

[image]

Kindly anyone help me to do the expected result

Recently got like below: when i use like  **[['']*1+['']*1+['Subjects'] * 2 + ['Grade'] * 2 + ['']*1, dfnew.columns]**
[image]

I want to remove empty row and first column which is created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with all columns which cannot be set to `MultiIndex` in columns and then assigh nested lists:

```
df = df.set_index(['Name','Std'])
df.columns = [['Subjects'] * 2 + ['Grade'] * 2, df.columns]
print (df)
            Subjects       Grade       
               Tamil Maths Score Result
Name    Std                            
Shankar 10        90   100   190   Pass
Kumar   10        50    20    70   Fail
```

Comment: one small changes in that question. I added last column as Status .That column not under Grade . Please look at that. and also am not able to write into excel after those changes. am getting the error like """NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented""". when am using df.to_excel("DetailsReports.xlsx", index=False) – Python Team 6 mins ago

Comment: @PythonTeam - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33711809) ?

Comment: Sorry i dont think that its related to mine. not able to understand :(

Comment: @PythonTeam - Use `df.to_excel("DetailsReports.xlsx", index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')`

Comment: Name, Std is getting next row when using the above answer. My expectation is Name,Std is in same row only. :( and also it display only one name as Shankar. Not displaying two times. I mentioned in the Expected Result as like i need to get.

Comment: i tried like this [['']*1+['']*1+['Subjects'] * 2 + ['Grade'] * 2 + ['']*1, dfnew.columns] . I got it but the problem is not getting Status column as Separate . It's come along with Grade part . and also next to headers it's created a empty row. and first column as 1,2 as index number. I don't want to show this.

Comment: @PythonTeam - So want column are join with `Subjects` and what columns with `Grade` ?

Comment: Tamil  Maths in Subjects and  Score Result in Grade. Status is Separate column

Comment: @PythonTeam - No, if use MultiIndex is necessary each column have 2 levels, so your solution working, you can check it by `dfnew.columns.tolist()`

Comment: @PythonTeam - Maybe question is why are necessary `MultiIndex` ? Or what is expected output?

Comment: I added my expected result above. Please look into that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184855/discussion-between-python-team-and-jezrael).

Comment: @PythonTeam - I understand now, testing and looking for solution.

Comment: @PythonTeam - Not easy, it seem is necessary use https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html?highlight=merged

Comment: Oh okay. I tried something but i got like the above output. i am not able to remove the empty row which is created automatically.

Comment: @PythonTeam - ya, need write columns separately and then data, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6618#issuecomment-382405067)