# How to save a dataframe in python so that it can not populate empty row in excel sheet?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` as follows:

```
A      B
AA     BB
-----------
2      1
3      4
5      8
9      7
```

This `dataframe` have multilevel column. To save in excel I am doing the following

```
col1= ["A","B"]

col2= ["AA","BB"]

r1 = [2,1]

r2 =[3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [col1,col2])

df.loc[(len(df))] = r1

df.to_excel("name.xlsx")
```

But in excel I can see one empty row automatically added between column name and data. How can I  save the `dataframe` in xlax format so that empty row will not populate?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the data frame creation portion of your code?

Comment: @MostafaShaminYeasar Code is added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a multi-index dataframe to Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710771/writing-a-multi-index-dataframe-to-excel-file)

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing but a bug of "to_excel" while processing multiindex.

Just use to_csv:

```
import pandas as pd
col1= ["A","B"]

col2= ["AA","BB"]

r1 = [2,1]

r2 =[3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [col1,col2])

df.loc[(len(df))] = r1
df.loc[(len(df))] = r2

df.to_csv("name.csv")
```

Comment: Want to save in excel format(xlsx). Is this possible to remove the bugs?

Comment: Not right now. I will share if I can find something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround - reset the column index:

```py
df.T.reset_index(level=1).T.to_excel("name.xlsx")

          A   B
level_1  AA  BB
0         2   1
```

---

To set custom names for the column levels (do this, and then export to excel):

- only one of the levels:

```py
df.columns.set_names('name_lev_2', level=1, inplace=True)

             A   B
name_lev_2  AA  BB
0            2   1
```

- both levels:

```py
df.rename_axis(columns=['name_lev_1', 'name_lev_2'])  # not in place

name_lev_1   A   B
name_lev_2  AA  BB
0            2   1
```